# Assuming FLRW is correct, can it be 3-torus?

Tags: cosmology, topology

Assuming [Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) is correct, can space topology be [3-torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-torus)? I.e. are these two hypotheses compatible?

Answer (score 4):

The assumption underlying the FLRW metric is that space is homogeneous and **locally isotropic**.

**Schur’s Theorem** states that a connected Riemann manifold of dimension $n>2$ that is locally isotropic around every point has constant sectional curvature $K$.

If $(M,g)$ is a Riemann 3-manifold with sectional curvature $K=0$ everywhere (such as the flat 3-torus $T^3$), then $(M,g)$ is **locally isometric** to the Euclidean space $E^3$.

The FLRW models are homogeneous and (locally) isotropic solutions of Einstein's field equations, of which the spatial sections have constant sectional curvature.

Relativistic cosmological models with topology $T^3$ and relativistic cosmological models with topology $E^3$ —assuming the same cosmic components and energy densities— **are described by exactly the same Robertson-Walker metric**, even though $T^3$ is finite in extent while $E^3$ is infinite. In particular, the solution of the Friedmann equations —the scale factor $a(t)$— is also identical. Only the boundary conditions on the spatial coordinates are changed.

Einstein's field equations are local PDEs that relate the metric and its derivatives at a point to the density and flux of energy and momentum at that point. EFEs determine the **local geometry of spacetime**. Although the local constraints imposed by the EFEs are very powerful (severely restricting what the spacetime manifold can do), they stop short of having a determining effect on the **global topology of space**. The spatial topology of the universe cannot be determined from its spatial curvature because each of the three plausible cosmic geometries —Euclidean, spherical, hyperbolic— is consistent with many different topologies.

The problem is that in most studies in cosmology the topology of the space-like hypersurfaces of the spacetime is assumed to be **simply-connected**: the hypersphere $S^3$, the Euclidean 3-space $E^3$, or the hyperbolic 3-space $H^3$. However, there is no particular reason for space to have a trivial topology, that is, the global topology of space does not have to be that of $E^3$, $S^3$, or $H^3$. There are a great variety of **multiply-connected topologies** for $K=0$, $K>0$, and $K<0$.

To sum up, $T^3$ is not globally isotropic, but is locally isometric to $E^3$. Consequently, cosmological models with spatial topology $T^3$ are described by the same FLRW metric as cosmological models with spatial topology $E^3$. The FLRW metric is perfectly compatible with a spacetime with the spatial topology of $T^3$.

NOTE. Here the expression "topology of space" is used in the sense "GLOBAL topology of space" (i.e. properties of the space that are not "local"), not in the technical meaning of topology as a collection of open sets.

Answer (score 0):

FLRW cosmology postulates that there exists a frame in which space is isotropic and homogenous, but a 3-torus is not globally isotropic. You can see this in that if you head along a (spatial) geodesic along a 3-torus whether you get back to your starting point and how far you have to travel before you do depends on the direction you go.

Comment: The assumptions underlying the FLRW metric are perfectly compatible with a spacetime with the global topology of $\mathbb R\times \mathrm T^3$.

Comment: @J.Murray I've said above the particular assumption (the cosmological principle) that isn't compatible and why, so I don't know what else to say.

Comment: Yes, and I’m saying that’s wrong. During the derivation of the FLRW metric, the descriptors “homogeneous and isotropic” are translated into precise conditions on the metric, which are not violated in a toroidal universe - see the model proposed by Starobinski and Zeldovich e.g. [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25334171.pdf).

Comment: @J.Murray the standard way to translate the cosmological principle in to a condition on FLRW spacetime is to demand that we can slice the spacetime in to spatial hypersuraces surfaces that are isotropic manifolds. Allowing space to be a homogenous, but non-isotropic manifold like a flat 3-torus can be seen as a minimal relaxation of the cosmological principle, but in the strictest sense it is not an FLRW spacetime.

Comment: Okay, that’s fair. I suppose it depends on whether you define  a FLRW spacetime via the assumptions of global homogeneity or isotropy or more generally in terms of the form of the metric (e.g. [here](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept03/Trodden/Trodden2.html).

Comment: @JohnDavis isn't 3-torus isotropic? Can we build isotropic looped flat spacetime?

Comment: @Dims the answer is only R^3, for flat space that is isotropic. These lecture notes cover what topologies are compatible with the comsological principle and why space can't be flat, isotropic and compact: http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~chirata/ph217/lec01.pdf